# Spring webapp loads white page after login due to incorrect CSRF token

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have a basic Spring (v5.3.23) web app running in an Apache Tomcat container (v9), and using eclipse as IDE. It uses Spring security for processing logins.

Everything runs almost correctly, but sometimes, after a successful login, the browser shows a white page, while there is no exception logged server-side or any other message. The problem appears both in development environment and production environment, so I don't think it's eclipse-related.

I have managed to pin down the problem to the following sequence :

1. Start tomcat container
2. Open login page in browser
3. After login, the secured home page is displayed correctly
4. Re-start tomcat (the problem occurs both when changes are made to the web app or not)
5. Refresh the browser, which redirects to login
6. Login again
7. **The blank page is shown, no exception logged, no log messages in console**

In this sequence, the problem occurs most of the time. If between steps 5 and 6 I refresh the page one more, meaning the login page is reloaded, the white page problem does not occur anymore, and the proper page is displayed.

A strong possibility is that it's something related to either the CSRF token in the login form or the JSESSION cookie of the container, but short of debugging through Spring code, I can't figure it out.

**LATER EDIT**

I narrowed down the issue to the CSRF token; if I change the value in the login form, I always get the blank page.

I have noticed the _csrf token has one value in the login form, then a different, but single value across all form that are used while the user is connected. Seems like the _csrf token is linked to the user session somehow.

The same happens when the login page is refreshed: different tokens in login & other app forms, but somehow,, sometimes, the initial token does not match what the server expects.